# How can I write this complex query in Laravel?

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have a query working perfect but I need it in ORM Laravel. 
I just need this query in eloquent Query builder.

```
SELECT * FROM product where vendor_id in (
  SELECT vendor_id from vendor where is_block = 0
);
```

> Scenario : There are two tables. One for `Product` and other for `Vendor`.
>   I want to select product from `Product` table. Each product belong to a vendor. If vendor is blocked then don't select product.
>   If `is_block` attribute is `0` then its mean that `vendor` is not block. If `is_blocked=1` then vendor is blocked. I need to select only products of a vendor whose is_block = 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`whereHas()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) method:

```
Product::whereHas('vendor', function($q) {
    $q->where('is_block', 0);
})->get();
```

Or the [`whereDoesntHave()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence) method:

```
Product::whereDoesntHave('vendor', function($q) {
    $q->where('is_block', 1);
})->get();
```

Make sure you've defined the relationship in the `Product` model:

```
public function vendor()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Vendor::class);
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain first query function santax? And what will it do?

Comment: @user6251750 it will filter product. It will get only those products, vendor of which has `is_block = 0`. You can learn more about the method by clicking the link.

Comment: No I need to know that why you use clover function in query please explain that santax of clover function ? Thank You

Comment: @user6251750 you mean [closure](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)? You may want to start from reading PHP and Laravel docs.